# Exactness of a function approximation

Tags: approximation, estimation

I've got a number of (measured) points $(x_i, y_i)$, which [theoretically] lie on a curve $y = \sin (x + A)$ for some unknown value of $A$. The points have inexact coordinates due to the measurement errors, we can assume that the deviation from the real points is bounded by $\delta_x$ in $x$-direction and $\delta_y$ in $y$-direction.

My goal is to make a good approximation of $A$ and establish how much the estimated $A$ may differ from the actual one, given the concrete set of $(x_i, y_i)$, and both $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$.

Alternatively (perhaps this is the same), I need to estimate what is the maximal possible deviation of an $y$-value, calculated by the formula $y = \sin (x + A_{\rm estimated})$ from the real value for an *arbitrary* $x$ (since $\sin$ is periodical, $x\in[0, \pi/2)$ would suffice).

In order to estimate the value of $A$, I think about using [LMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm). But I cannot find any theoretical upper bound of the deviation between estimated and actual parameter $A$.

Am I on the right way? How can I estimate the exactness of the approximation? Is LMA applicable here or is there a better way?

---

Additional question: Can the exactness be deduced just from the estimated $A$ without knowing what was the way of obtaining it?

Comment: This looks like data reconciliation. Did you think about orthogonal distance regression ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Perhaps it is; I briefly looked through [an article about ODR](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odr_ams.pdf) but didn't find any upper bounds on the estimation exactness. Could you perhaps give some references? What should I read on the topic? I'm quite new to this branch of mathematics.

Comment: I agree with this point (I was involved in the ODR project in the mid-80's. In fact, your problme is **exactly** data reconciliation which produces a lot of statistical information about the reconciled values;

Comment: https://du.co/solutions/reconciliation/?utm_term=%2Bdata%20%2Breconciliation&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=Strategic+-+Always+On+Search+Campaign+-+The+Marketing+Pod&utm_source=adwords&hsa_ad=474149426523&hsa_src=g&hsa_ver=3&hsa_tgt=kwd-302335753396&hsa_cam=9714885285&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_grp=103231878205&hsa_acc=5952101529&hsa_kw=%2Bdata%20%2Breconciliation&hsa_mt=b&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxaKn_q6v7QIVnhoGAB2BhQAMEAAYAyAAEgJXQvD_BwE

Comment: http://okfnlabs.org/reconcile-csv/

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Your links point to some tools, right? Because I'm primary interested in error estimation.